# How to match this string use Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, string-matching, parentheses

I have two string:

```
(123)4567890
1234567890
```

The pair `(` and `)` must both present, or both omit. Currently I use this Regex:

```
(?:(?:\(\d{3}\))|(?:\d{3}))\d{7}
```

which use `OR` to match one of two case:

```
\(\d{3}\)
\d{3}
```

Just for curious, how can I check for last match (have `(` or not) in current match (check for `)`)?
Can you suggest me another way to achieve same result?

Comment: Try [`(\()?\d{3}(?(1)\))\d{7}`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5c%28%29%3f%5cd%7b3%7d%28%3f%281%29%5c%29%29%5cd%7b7%7d&i=%28123%294567890%0d%0a1234567890%0d%0a123%294567890)

Comment: A great opportunity to use a conditional clause, but Wiktor beat me to it. You could also use a simple alternator for a clunkier but easier-to-read solution (if that's a concern) `^(?:\(\d{3}\)\d{7}|\d{10})$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank for solution. Work perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use a [**conditional construct**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/alternation-constructs-in-regular-expressions#Conditional_Expr): capture an optional opening `(` and then match 3 digits, and then check if Group 1 is empty, and if not, match the closing `)`:

```
(\()?\d{3}(?(1)\))\d{7}
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5C%28%29%3F%5Cd%7B3%7D%28%3F%281%29%5C%29%29%5Cd%7B7%7D&i=%28123%294567890%0D%0A1234567890%0D%0A123%294567890). Add anchors/boundaries as per requirements.

**Details**

- `(\()?` - An optional capturing group 1 matching a `(` char
- `\d{3}` - 3 digits
- `(?(1)\))` - If Group 1 matched, match a `)`
- `\d{7}` - 7 digits.

Comment: Thank for solution :)